# Windows cannot find Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v5.10.exe

Tags: windows, azure

Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\AMIR\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v5.10.exe'.Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run it directly from the following path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe`?

Comment: this error has been shown automatically every 5 minutes @GauravMantri

Comment: Check your startup folder and remove any shortcuts that refer to `Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v5.10.exe`.

Comment: Run it as admin.

Comment: Nothing in my startup folder @GauravMantri

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was Kaspersky antivirus was blocked
we have to add Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator - v5.10  to trusted applications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cueNJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saibc.png)